# Personal blog using Django

Tags: python, django, html, css

I am interested in creating a personal blog using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).
I have used cms like Wordpress/Durpal, but am unsatisfied with its over simplicity. I want something challenging or different. Also I am a Python newbie--I got inspired by [Stevelosh](http://stevelosh.com/projects/stevelosh-com/), but couldn't find enough resources to build such a site. Can someone put light in my path? ;)

Also are there any similar frameworks like Django?
It should be

1. Typographically clean and beautiful
2. HTML5/CSS3 capable

Comment: Seriously, you couldn't find any Django-powered blog engines? Did you actually try searching?

Comment: http://blog.montylounge.com/2010/02/10/eleven-django-blog-engines-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

You can use django, or any server side framework, with any client side framework. There are **many**, but according to your criterias, I've selected a few:

- [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)
- [easyframework](http://easyframework.com/)
- [blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about)

Answer (score 0):

Django can certainly be used to create a typographically clean and beautiful blog in HTML5 / CSS3 but it doesn't provide, for example, a basic blog template or a CMS. If you're interested in building a blog entirely (both the look and feel as well as the underlying functionality) then Django is a good choice.

You can create HTML pages on your own so they'll look and behave exactly as you wish. It's not like WordPress that you can install and configure to have a blog up and running. However, there are many Django packages that you can add to your Django installation to easily create a blog.

Answer (score 0):

There are many CMS (content management system) apps for Django. For instance, [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/) is well maintained and has been around for a while. My guess is that it's pretty solid. The [Django CMS Apps Comparison](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CMSAppsComparison) page shows many alternatives in a matrix, and seems to be fairly recent (last updated 2 months ago).